# Как написать модель нейронной сети с использованием метода "без учителя"

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

У меня есть временные данные (зависимость времени от температуры в комнате) и я хочу прогнозировать время нагрева, то есть за какое время у меня нагреется комната, если сейчас температура в ней 20 градусов, а я хочу 24. Я хочу воспользоваться LSTM моделью. А так же, у меня данные без правильных ответов, то есть модель без учителя. Каким методом обучения я могу воспользоваться, и в чем будет плюсы и минусы того или иного метода обучения? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Пример У меня есть комната, она обогревается, и я устанавливаю желаемую температуру. И у меня нейронная сеть прогнозирует время, за сколько у меня нагреется или охладиться комната. Я устанавливаю температуру 20, а у меня температура в комнате 24, мне нейронная сеть пишет, за 2 часа у меня все охладиться. Или наоборот, у меня в комнате 18 а хочу нагреть до 22 мне нейронная сеть пишет,за 2 часа и 40 минут все нагреется

Вот пример данных. Тут видно, что за 2 часа мы нагрелись до 24 градусов, как установлено в set_temperature
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Здесь](https://github.com/7wafer7/test_nn_) полный набор данных, который с использую

Comment: Что-тостранное вы пишете. Что значит "прогнозировать время"? ВременнОй ряд  - это последовательность значений, измеренных в последовательные моменты времени. И прогнозируются именно значения.  "Без учителя" -  для временного ряда смысла не имеет,т.к. сначала обучается модель по историческим значениям временного ряда (т.е. с учителем), а уж потом, с помощью этой модели делается предсказания.  Если вы пишете что решили воспользоваться моделью LSTM - то про какие "методы обучения" вы спрашиваете? Вобщем -  переформулируйте вопрос в принятой и понятной всем терминологии и вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: @passant Я понял свою ошибку и дополнил описание

Comment: Зависимость времени чего у вас от температуры? Приведите пример данных и лучше побольше, без этого будут абстрактные разговоры. Пример данных и их описание добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я внес изменения

Comment: Да, так гораздо понятнее. Теперь вам нужно чётко сформулировать задачу. У вас есть набор данных - текущая температура, выставленная температура, температура на улице - и вы хотите знать, сколько времени займёт достижение температурой комнаты выставленной температуры, так? Тут нужно будет сообразить, как правильно данные подготовить / сгруппировать, но сначала нужно чётко сформулировать задачу: у меня на входе то-то, а на выходе я хочу то-то. Задача нетривиальная, но мне кажется она сведётся к линейной регрессии в итоге.

Comment: @CrazyElf У меня есть входные данные, вот эти все 8 штук (в таблице может быть 7, если переводить время в unix, то дата и время будут в одном столбце, перевожу в unix, потому что нейросеть понимает только такие временные данные. Я же прав?). Я хочу предсказать время. Ко мне будут приходить одна строчка данные, а нейросеть должна сказать мне, за сколько я нагрею\охлажу помещение

Comment: @CrazyElf Я думал на счет линейную модель. Но есть вопросы. Сможет ли линейная модель увидеть зависимости в данных? Смогу ли я обучить нейронную сеть или линейную модель без метки ответов? Если будут какие нибудь колебания в данные, предположим у меня в комнате кондиционер работает, но конечно я не нагрею комнату за указанное время, сможет ли линейная модель с этим справиться?

Comment: А это всё надо будет проверять. Первым шагом я бы попробовал найти концы цепочек, т.е. когда t комнаты (с какой-то точностью) равна выставленной. Потом идти назад по времени и добавлять в тренировочные данные строку с данными и таргетом: разницей между временем конца цепочки и текущим временем этой строки. Потом полученный датасет скормить линейной регрессии и дальше смотреть что там с качеством предсказания и т.д. Потом какие-то промежуточные данные добавлять, усреднения и прочие аггрегации пробовать. Но надо с чего-то же начать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, я как раз сейчас на этом. Я думаю как мне представить время нагрева (концы цепочек). А так же как представить время охлаждения комнаты. Я сделал так, перевожу время в секунды, когда температура в комнате и установленная, совпадает. Если нужно было охладить помещение, просто делаю отрицательное время, если нагреть, но положительное

Comment: А, там возможно ещё нужно не просто температуру, а разницу температур брать в данные, так и знак нужный будет.

Comment: Я делаю так. Я смотрю, когда в столбце set_temperature была поменяна температура и смотрю на время, запоминаю ее. Смотрю, когда температура в комнате (room_temperature) и установленная (set_temperature) совпадает и делаю разность

Comment: @CrazyElf Просто мне нужно помощь с представлением времени. Как я еще могу представить время нагрева или охлаждения ?

Comment: Ну да, так вроде хорошо должно быть, как вы делаете. Как вариант.

Comment: В общем добавьте прямо файл с данными, и код который получился. Если это не секретное всё. Я попробую посмотреть как время будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf Куда? Где мне предоставить вам данные?

Comment: Выкладываете в какое-то файлохранилище - гугл, яндекс, любое - и добавляете ссылку в вопрос. Можно и на GitHub и тоже ссылку в вопрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я разместил файлик с данными. Нормального кода пока у меня нет, есть тестовые, но это что бы проверить те или иные гипотезы о данных

Comment: @CrazyElf Единственная проблема, я пока не знаю как мне сделать передачу времени

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148950/discussion-between-7wafer7-and-crazyelf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас довольно странные данные, с ними надо ещё разбираться и я не очень понимаю, как это всё трактовать. Попробуем просто нарисовать графики выставленной температуры и температуры в комнате.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_url = "https://github.com/7wafer7/test_nn_/raw/main/df_git_hud.xls"
df = pd.read_excel(data_url)
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'].astype(str), dayfirst=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5)) 
sns.lineplot(data=df[['DateTime', 'set_temperature', 'room_temperature']].set_index('DateTime'));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зависимость какая-то есть, но довольно странная. Либо какие-то датчики врут, либо я чего-то не понимаю. При выставлении температуры 20 температура стремится где-то к 23. А при выставлении 24 улетает на 26. Ну и гуляет ещё туда-сюда сама по себе. Плюс какие-то странные провалы до 20, а то и до 18 при переключении температуры на более высокую. То ли проветривают при этом помещение, то ли что-то выключается на время, непонятно.

**Update.** Посмотрим покрупнее на один день - с 13 часов одного дня до 13 часов другого дня, этот шаблон явно повторяется примерно в одном виде каждый день.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[(df['DateTime'] > '2022-01-25 13:00') & (df['DateTime'] < '2022-01-26 13:00'), ['DateTime', 'set_temperature', 'room_temperature']].set_index('DateTime'));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут ещё лучше видно, что выставленная температура в 20 градусов не достигается, она достигается только после выставления 24 градусов, видимо, проветриванием помещения. А вот температура в 24 градуса действительно достигается за какое-то время (и проскакивается). Не исключено, что это достигается просто закрыванием окна. Хотите ли вы предсказывать именно это время - за сколько будет достигнута температура 24 градуса после её выставления? Вот это можно сделать, если такая частичная задача имеет смысл. Если именно это нужно, я могу продолжить изыскания.

**Update2.** Я извлёк сами события. Их мало и разброс довольно большой.

```py
data = []
end_dt = None
end_t = None
min_t = None
min_dt = None

for i, row in df.sort_values('DateTime', ascending=False).iterrows():
    if row['set_temperature'] != 24:
        end_dt = None
        continue
    if end_dt is None:
        if abs(row['room_temperature'] - 24) < 0.8:
            end_dt = row['DateTime']
            min_t = row['room_temperature']
            end_t = min_t
            min_dt = None
    else:
        if row['room_temperature'] < min_t:
            min_t = row['room_temperature']
            min_dt = row['DateTime']
        elif row['room_temperature'] > min_t:
            if min_dt is not None and min_t < 23:
                print(min_dt, end_dt, min_t, end_t, end_t - min_t, end_dt - min_dt)
                d = row.to_dict()
                d['temp_delta'] = end_t - min_t
                d['dt_delta'] = end_dt - min_dt
                data.append(d)
            end_dt = None
            min_dt = None
            min_t = None
```

Вывод:

```
2022-02-01 04:00:14 2022-02-01 05:20:14 19.82 24.36 4.539999999999999 0 days 01:20:00
2022-02-01 01:20:14 2022-02-01 01:30:14 22.31 24.54 2.2300000000000004 0 days 00:10:00
2022-01-31 03:20:14 2022-01-31 04:40:14 17.57 23.88 6.309999999999999 0 days 01:20:00
2022-01-28 03:50:14 2022-01-28 04:40:14 20.56 24.78 4.220000000000002 0 days 00:50:00
2022-01-27 03:00:10 2022-01-27 04:30:14 20.62 24.99 4.369999999999997 0 days 01:30:04
2022-01-26 03:30:14 2022-01-26 04:50:14 20.91 24.99 4.079999999999998 0 days 01:20:00
```

Т.е. нагрев на 4 градуса где-то за 1 час и 20 минут - типовое событие. Но 6 событий - это очень мало для построения каких-либо моделей.

**Update3.** Но всё же попытаемся построить модель.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data)
y = df_temp['dt_delta'].dt.seconds/60
X = df_temp.drop(columns = ['dt_delta', 'Date', 'Time', 'DateTime', 'relay_off_on'])
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
print(lr.score(X, y))
df_coeff = pd.DataFrame({'field': X.columns, 'value': lr.coef_})
df_coeff
sns.barplot(x='value', y='field', data=df_coeff.sort_values('value'))
plt.title(f'Intersept: {lr.intercept_}')
```

Хм, отличный скор получается - 1.0! Но какой же признак оказался главным при этом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скорость ветра решает! Чем больше скорость ветра, тем меньшее время нужно для нагрева комнаты до 24 градусов. ))  Ну это явно какой-то бред. Попробуем выкинуть скорость ветра. Да и `temp_delta` тоже надо бы выкинуть, у нас этого значения на самом деле нет в данных изначально, я его чисто для справки добавлял.

```py
X = df_temp.drop(columns = ['dt_delta', 'Date', 'Time', 'DateTime', 'relay_off_on', 'wind_speed', 'temp_delta])
```

Скор стал хуже - примерно 0.91, а проблемы с логикой всё-равно остались.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не может быть такого, что чем горячее радиатор и больше температура на улице, тем дольше будет идти нагрев комнаты, это какая-то ерунда. В общем, данных мало для нормальной модели, как ни крути.

А если оставить в модели в итоге одну только температуру комнаты, то скор станет совсем плохой и предсказания будут совсем уже приблизительные.

Comment: Там просто немного датчик чувствительный, из за этого бывало просадки.

Comment: И скорее всего там окно открыто. Из за этого просадки

Comment: Да. Данные адекватные, просто есть странности. Я уже поработал с ними и понял, что мне лучше найти другой дата сет

Comment: Вы могли бы помочь найти дата сет. Мне нужно предсказывать за какое время нагреется комната, при таких-то, значениях. Я просто не смог найти такого

Comment: Ну, я ещё посмотрел на данные, можно попробовать предсказать время нагрева до 24 градусов и по этому датасету. Новый датасет я не очень понимаю, где искать. Если такая частичная задача подойдёт - нагревание до 24 градусов, то можно её попробовать решить. Но у вас получится всего 6 таких событий, этого очень мало для машинного обучения, результат будет очень приблизительный и не факт, что мы что-то реальное предскажем, не зная главного - когда открывали и закрывали окно. Может это там основной фактор вообще, а вовсе не выставляемая температура.

Comment: Вот кстати что-то может быть похожее на то, что вам нужно, но там надо ещё покопаться https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/claytonmiller/open-smart-home-iotieqenergy-data

Comment: Ещё вот это близко, но тут нет термостата, есть температура и датчики окна ))  https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mattpo/temperature-iot-on-gcp

Comment: Я не знаю как вас благодарить. Проделана большая работа, вы мне помогли и показали, как можно данные крутить и смотреть на них. Я учту все что вы мне написали. Ваш ответ мне очень помог. Спасибо вам

Comment: Я не знаю как вас благодарить. Проделана большая работа, вы мне помогли и показали, как можно данные крутить и смотреть на них. Я учту все что вы мне написали. Ваш ответ мне очень помог. Спасибо вам

Comment: Еще один вопрос. Как я должен предоставлять время `DateTime` для нейронной сети, что бы она поняла, что это время, а не набор цифр

Comment: В этом дате сете  время измеряли для каждого прибора отдельно, то есть данные не совпадают по времени. Немного не понимаю что тут происходит https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/claytonmiller/open-smart-home-iotieqenergy-data/data

Comment: С временем сложно. Хорошим признаком может оказаться и просто время суток (часы от полуночи например, или минуты или секунды). А может быть нужен промежуток времени между событиями. В чистом виде дата-время только при работе с временными рядами наверное может использоваться, но это отдельный вид задач, я его не сильно разбирал.

Comment: С теми датасетами я пока не разбирался толком, пока ничего сказать не могу. А так то, что я вам показал - это маленькая часть исследовательской работы дата сайентиста. Там ещё очень много чего можно сделать, если есть нормальные данные - выбор модели, более сложный выбор признаков и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо вам, за вашу помочь и потраченное время <3 <3 <3

Comment: я смог наконец то выделить время и посмотреть эти данные, и я скажу, что мне они вообще не нравиться. Абсолютно непонятные данные. и температура меняется тоже очень странно

Comment: Я про вот этот дата сет https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/claytonmiller/open-smart-home-iotieqenergy-data/?select=LICENSE.md

Comment: Не могу ничем помочь. Не знаю, где нормальные датасеты найти )